# JavaScript Stripe Table Rows Abstracted Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, abstract

My question is:  How do I loop through the  tags so that I can stripe the table rows?  Keep in mind:  If the solution is in the stripeRows() function, it must be abstracted (no reference to a tag name, classname, etc).  The function stripes the rows of a table which I think will be obvious if you look at the JavaScript code.

It is mostly done (I think) but I am having trouble with one aspect of the file.  The solution must be abstracted and solved without editing the HTML or CSS, no jQuery and no innerHTML.

Do I need to loop through the rows in the stripeMeTable() and webcoursesTable() function or the stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) function?

I am including my HTML and JavaScript below.

I need the JavaScript file to work with both of the HTML pages.

OK, here's the code.  Thanks for you help.

HTML Code(page 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Striped Tables</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="striped-tables.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="striped-tables.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Striped Tables</h1>
<table id="stripeme">
  <tr>
    <th>Food</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lines">
    <td>Chocolate</td>
    <td>delicious</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shrimp</td>
    <td>delicious</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lines">
    <td>Brussel sprouts</td>
    <td>vile</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Raspberry</td>
    <td>delicious</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lines">
    <td>Tofu</td>
    <td>not even a real food</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pizza</td>
    <td>delicious</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lines">
    <td>Honey</td>
    <td>never spoils</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML (page 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Is your script abstracted?</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="abstraction.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="striped-tables.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Another Striped Table</h1>
<table id="webcourses">
  <tr>
    <th>Course number</th>
    <th>Course content</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="core_course">
    <td>WEB-140</td>
    <td>design principles</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="core_course">
    <td>WEB-115</td>
    <td>XHTML and beginning CSS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="core_course">
    <td>WEB-210</td>
    <td>advanced CSS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>WEB-215</td>
    <td>JavaScript</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>WEB-182</td>
    <td>PHP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>WEB-250</td>
    <td>integration of MySQL and PHP</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript File:

```
addLoadEvent(stripemeTable);
addLoadEvent(webcoursesTable);

function stripemeTable() {
    // get the <tr> tags:
    var stripemeRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    // IF the tableID is NOT stripeme, exit the stripemeTable function:
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementsByTagName || !document.getElementById('stripeme'))  {
        return false;
    // ELSE loop through the rows and use the stripeRows function:  
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < stripemeRows.length; i++) {
            stripeRows('stripeme','pri-stripe','sec-stripe','over-stripe');
        } // end of the rows FOR loop 
    } // end of the tableID test IF/ELSE
} // end of the stripemeTable function

function webcoursesTable() {
    // get the <tr> tags
    var webcoursesRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    // IF the tableID is NOT webcourses, exit the  webcoursesTable function:
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementsByTagName || !document.getElementById('webcourses'))  {  
        return false;   
    // ELSE loop through the rows and use the stripeRows function:  
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < webcoursesRows.length; i++) {
            stripeRows('stripeme','pri-stripe','sec-stripe','over-stripe');
        } // end of the rows FOR loop 
    } // end of the tableID test IF/ELSE
} // end of the webcoursesTable function

function stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) {
    // get a table with a tableID
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    // loop through the table rows:
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // get the current className of the table rows:
        var oldClassName = rows[i].className;

        // append the even className to the oldClassName:
        var even = rows[i].oldClassName;
        even += " " + even;

        // append the over className to the oldClassName:
        var over = rows[i].oldClassName;
        over += " " + over;

        // IF the table row is the first row, do not stripe that row:
        if (rows[0]) {
            addClass(rows[0],oldClassName);
        // ELSE IF the table rows are odd, stripe the rows with the odd class:
        } else if (rows[i]/2 != 0 && !rows[0]) {  
            addClass(rows[i],odd);
        // ELSE the table rows are even, stripe the rows with the even class:
        } else {  
            addClass(rows[i],even);
        } // end of the first/even/odd rows IF

        // handle the onmouseover event for the table rows:
        mouseOver = rows[i].onmouseover;
        mouseOver = function() {
            addClass(rows[i],over);
        } // end of the onmouseover anonymous function

        // handle the onmouseout event for the table rows:
        mouseOut = rows[i].onmouseout;
        mouseOut = function() {
            addClass(rows[i],oldClassName);
        } // end of the onmouseout anonymous function
    } // end of the table rows FOR loop 
} // end of the stripeRows function 

function addClass(element,theClass) {
    // IF the table row does not have a className, append the required className:
    if (!element.className) {
        element.className = theClass;
    // ELSE append the required className to the className(s) that are already assigned to that row:
    } else {
        var newClassName = element.className;
        newClassName += " ";
        newClassName += theClass;
        element.className = newClassName;
    } // end of the className IF/ELSE  
} // end of the addClass function

function addLoadEvent(func) {
    // assign the window.onload function to a variable:
    var oldonload = window.onload;

    // IF the window.onload does not call a function:
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    // ELSE set the window.load:
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload();
            func();
        } // end of the oldonload anonymous function
    } // end of the typeof IF
} // end of the addLoadEvent function
```

The lines that I think are the problem (keep in mind, the function needs to stay as is and I can't reference a tag name in the stripeRows() function).  The problem is:  How to loop through the rows in a general, abstracted way in the stripeRows() function:

```
function stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) {
    // get a table with a tableID
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    // get the table rows:
    var rows = tableID.rows;

    // loop through the table rows:
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
```

Comment: if the loop thru the elements is necessary in the striperows() function, then no: can't reference the <tr> tag.  It must be abstracted.  If I can loop thru the <tr> tags in the stripemeTable and webcoursesTable() functions, then I can refer to the <tr> tags.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `getElementsByTagName`. Table and table section elements have a *rows* property that is their child rows. So you can do something like:

```
function stripeRows(tableSection, oddClass, evenClass) {
  var rows = tableSection.rows;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    rows[i].className = i%2? oddClass : evenClass;
  }
}
```

Note that "tableSection" can be either a table, tBody, tHead or tFoot element. And you can use an "addClass" function to add the class, I've kept it simple as an example.

#### Edit

Some comments on the code:

```
function stripemeTable() {
    // get the <tr> tags:
    var stripemeRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

that returns all the tr elements in the document, it might be better to do this table by table.

```
// IF the tableID is NOT stripeme, exit the stripemeTable function:
if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementsByTagName || !document.getElementById('stripeme'))  {
    return false;
```

here you test for `getElementsByTagName`, but it's used in the line above. If you really need to test for getElementById (and it's pretty rare now that it's not supported), consider:

```
     var stripeMe = document && document.getElementById && document.getElementById('stripeme');
     if (stripeMe) {
```

You also assume that the rows are from the table 'stripeMe' without actually testing that. If you want to stripe the rows only if they're in a table element with an ID of 'stripeMe' then do that. A class would be better though. Anyhow, the else is now redundant, just carry on:

```
// ELSE loop through the rows and use the stripeRows function:  
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < stripemeRows.length; i++) {
        stripeRows('stripeme','pri-stripe','sec-stripe','over-stripe');
    } // end of the rows FOR loop 
} // end of the tableID test IF/ELSE
```

instead:

```
     var stripemeRows = stripeMe.rows;
     for (var .... ) {
       ...
     }
```

Also, if you only want to stripe the rows in the body, then put the header rows in a tHead element and stripe only the rows in the table body, e.g.

```
 var stripemeRows = stripeMe.tBodies[0].rows;
```

Comment: RobG, thanks for your help.  I can't get that to work, I get this error:  TypeError: rows is undefined

Comment: Rob, I think I need to find a way to loop thru the <tr> tags in the abstracted function.  But I can't reference the <tr> tags.  I need something like var rows = tableID.getElementsByTagName(tag); and then loop thru the rows.  But I'm not sure how to do this.  I will edit the code above with the lines of code that I think are the problem.

Comment: function stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) {
     // get a table with a tableID
     var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

     // get the table rows:
     var rows = tableID.rows;

Comment: @JasonMcCoy—isn't that pretty much what the first function I posted does? Except you want to pass a table ID instead of a tableSection. I think you can work that one out.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but how does the stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) function know how to assign the classNames depending on the table row?  Inside the stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) function, I need to have a general(abstract) way to refer to the rows that need to be striped.

Comment: Every [table](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-table-element) and [tableSection](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#htmltablesectionelement) has a [rows](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-table-rows) property that is its rows, that's how you get the rows without `getElementsByTagName` (see my first function, `var rows = tableSection.rows;`).

Comment: but I get an error if I use this that says: rows is undefined

Comment: What sort of object are you trying to get the `rows` property of? Is it a [table](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-table-element) or [table section](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#htmltablesectionelement) element?

Comment: I am getting tables if that have an id attached to it. That tableID is the first parameter of the stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) function. Then I need to loop thru the rows of those tables.  If the HTML code had another table with just a <table> tag, that table would NOT get its rows striped.  But if a table has <table id="id">, then that table WOULD have its rows striped.

Comment: Then `var rows = document.getElementById('stripeme').rows;` will get the rows of table with ID 'stripeme'.

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't solve the problem with the stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) function.  Still need a general way to loop thru a tag without referring to the tag name.

Comment: I don't understand youre requirements then, my function doesn't use tagName anywhere.

Comment: Rob, yes your function doesn't use a tagName but the problem is the stripeRows function.  The tables won't be striped unless the looping issue inside the stripeRows function is dealt with.  The stripeRows function is the one that needs a loop without referring to a tagName or tableID.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few hints for you:

In the function stripRows the variable rows is used but not defined, you probably meant to have something like `var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');` near the beginning of that function.

Later in the same function you have `} else if (rows[i]/2 != 0 && !rows[0]) {`.  More than likely you meant `} else if (i%2 == 0...){`.  In fact that whole if...then could be better written as

```
if( i%2 == 0 ) {
    addClass(rows[i],'even');
} else {
    addClass(rows[i],'odd');
}
```

I hope that helps -- most of the rest of the errors errors are quite similar, so these two things should help you get going.

Comment: Thanks Sammy but I need a way to do it in an abstract(general) way in the stripeRows(tableID,odd,even,over) function without referring to a specific tag name like 'tr'

Answer (score 0):

@Jason-McCoy, without knowing the full restrictions, I think this meets all your requirements.  The first line is not stripped (by initializing `i` to 1 instead of zero), and the stripeRows function does not do any actual selections (by referencing the elements that are passed to it).  This will get the striping working, but take a close look at the `onmouseover` code, there are still bugs there.

```
addLoadEvent(stripeme);

function stripeme() {
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementsByTagName )
    { return false; }

    // IF the tableID is NOT webcourses, exit the  webcoursesTable function:
    if ( !document.getElementById('webcourses') && !document.getElementById('stripeme'))
    { return false; }

    // get the <tr> tags:
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i=1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        stripeRows(rows[i],(i%2==0)?'pri-stripe':'sec-stripe','over-stripe');
    } // end of the rows FOR loop 
} // end of the stripemeTable function

function stripeRows(row,rowClass,over) {
    addClass(row,rowClass);

    // get the current className of the table rows:
    var oldClassName = row.className;

    // handle the onmouseover event for the table rows:
    mouseOver = row.onmouseover;
    mouseOver = function() {
        addClass(row,over);
    } // end of the onmouseover anonymous function

    // handle the onmouseout event for the table rows:
    mouseOut = row.onmouseout;
    mouseOut = function() {
        addClass(row,oldClassName);
    } // end of the onmouseout anonymous function
} // end of the stripeRows function 

function addClass(element,theClass) {
    // IF the table row does not have a className, append the required className:
    if (!element.className) {
        element.className = theClass;
    // ELSE append the required className to the className(s) that are already assigned to that row:
    } else {
        var newClassName = element.className;
        newClassName += " ";
        newClassName += theClass;
        element.className = newClassName;
    } // end of the className IF/ELSE  
} // end of the addClass function

function addLoadEvent(func) {
    // assign the window.onload function to a variable:
    var oldonload = window.onload;

    // IF the window.onload does not call a function:
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    // ELSE set the window.load:
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload();
            func();
        } // end of the oldonload anonymous function
    } // end of the typeof IF
} // end of the addLoadEvent function
```

and for your css:
*either put this in both `striped-tables.css` and `abstraction.css` or include the same css file in both html files*

```
.pri-stripe
{
    background-color:green;
}

.sec-stripe
{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you SammyO, that looks like that is exactly what I need but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I've added the CSS that I am using.  Both HTML files display striped tables.  If that is not what you are seeing - what do you see?